# is not a template type

Tags: c++, templates, types

I am getting more and more in touch with generic templates which means, I am still no expert. I adapted the idea of the implementation of a template for objects and pointers (C++ special edition section 13.5) to my graph implementation but I am stuck for days now.

I have three header files and commented out every method declaration and implementation to get closer to the following and still coming errors:

> In file included from DirectedGraph.cpp:8:0:
>   DirectedGraph.h:16:48: error: ‘DirectedGraph’ is not a template type
>        template class DirectedGraph : public Graph
>
> DirectedGraph.h:45:22: error: ‘DirectedGraph’ is not a class template
>        template<> class DirectedGraph : public Graph
>
> DirectedGraph.h:45:50: error: ‘DirectedGraph’ is not a template type
>        template<> class DirectedGraph : public Graph
>
> DirectedGraph.h:74:48: error: ‘DirectedGraph’ is not a class template
>        template class DirectedGraph : private Graph
>
> DirectedGraph.h:74:80: error: ‘DirectedGraph’ is not a template type

```
// Graph.h
template<class V_type, class E_type> class Graph
{    };

template<> class Graph<void *, void *>
{    };

template<class V_type, class E_type> class Graph<V_type *, E_type *> : public Graph<void *, void *>
{    };


// Vertex.h
template<class V_type, class E_type> class Vertex
{
    friend class DirectedGraph;
};

template<> class Vertex<void *, void *>
{
    friend class DirectedGraph;
};

template<class V_type, class E_type> class Vertex<V_type *, E_type *> : private Vertex<void *, void *>
{
    friend class DirectedGraph;
};


// DirectedGraph.h
template<class V_type, class E_type> class DirectedGraph : public ggraph::Graph<V_type, E_type>
{    };

template<> class DirectedGraph<void *, void *> : public ggraph::Graph<void *, void *>
{    };

template<class V_type, class E_type> class DirectedGraph<V_type *, E_type *> : private ggraph::Graph<void *, void *>
{    };
```

Comment: clang reports an entirely different error, namely redefinition (which makes sense, since the friend decls are not templates)

Comment: You probably mean `friend class DirectedGraph<V_type, E_type>` and `friend class DirectedGraph<void*, void*>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the question derived `DirectedGraph` from `ggraph::Graph`, so it's necessary to put at least `Graph` in a `ggraph` namespace.

Try:

```
namespace ggraph
{
// Graph.h
template<class V_type, class E_type> class Graph
{    };

template<> class Graph<void *, void *>
{    };

template<class V_type, class E_type> class Graph<V_type *, E_type *> : public Graph<void *, void *>
{    };


// Vertex.h
template<class V_type, class E_type> class Vertex
{
    template <V_type, E_type> friend class DirectedGraph;
};

template<> class Vertex<void *, void *>
{
    template <class V_type = void*, class E_type = void*> friend class DirectedGraph;
};

template<class V_type, class E_type> class Vertex<V_type *, E_type *> : private Vertex<void *, void *>
{
    template <void*, void*> friend class DirectedGraph;
};


// DirectedGraph.h
template<class V_type, class E_type> class DirectedGraph : public ggraph::Graph<V_type, E_type>
{    };

template<> class DirectedGraph<void *, void *> : public ggraph::Graph<void *, void *>
{    };

template<class V_type, class E_type> class DirectedGraph<V_type *, E_type *> : private ggraph::Graph<void *, void *>
{    };

} // namespace ggraph
```

Comment: @SirTobi they all look the same after a while ;-).  Cheers.

Comment: anyone know why we need namespace around it ?

Comment: @bicepjai: the code in the question derived `DirectedGraph` from `ggraph::Graph`, so it's necessary to put at least `Graph` in a `ggraph` namespace.